# Read content of file passed in argument to perl program

Tags: perl, file

I am trying read content of file which I passed as command line argument to perl program

**ERROR:**

```
[localhost@dharm myPerlCodes]$ perl data.pl m
FILE NAME IS ==
Could not read from , program halting. at data.pl line 31.
```

**CODE:**

```
sub get_record {
 # the file_data should be passed in as a parameter
    my $file = shift;
    print "FILE NAME IS == $file\n";
    open(FILE, $file) or die "Could not read from $file, program halting.";
    # read the record, and chomp off the newline
    chomp(my $record = <FILE>);
    close FILE;
    return $record;
}

  $text = &get_record();
  print "text in given file is = $text\n";
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing the filename to get_record, like:

```
$text = &get_record(shift @ARGV);
```

shift inside a subroutine gets arguments passed to the subroutine (@_); only outside of a subroutine does it get command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of a function, `shift` returns the next parameter to the script, but inside of a function it returns the next parameter.

You need to pass the parameter in to the `get_record` function: `$text = &get_record(shift);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the content of a file passed as a parameter, you don't need to do any of that. The file will automatically be available in `<>`. Also, there's no need to use `&` unless you're dealing with prototypes (and you shouldn't be).

```
sub get_record {
    chomp( my $record = <> );
    return $record;
}

my $text = get_record();
```